# Writing integral in one variable as double integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

Let $f(x,y):\mathbb{R^2\to R}$ be a function in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Assume y is a function of $x$, means $y=y(x)$. Then one can take integration only in respect to $x$, i.e. $$I=\int_a^bf(x,y(x))dx.$$ I wonder wheter I can write this single integral as a double integral like $$I=\int_\tilde{a}^\tilde{b}\int_{y(a)}^{y(b)} g(x,y)dydx.$$ Can I do it?

Comment: Suppose that we have $y(b)=y(a)$. Then your first integral $I$ need not to be $0$, but your second expression is $0$.

Comment: @Kelenner and if $y(b)\neq y(a)$? Then it'll be possible?

Comment: Yes, but with no particular conditions on $g(x,u)$, there is trivial solutions: for example $g(x,u)=cf(x,y(x))u$ if $y(b)^2\not =y(a)^2$,  $c=2/(y(b)^2-y(a)^2)$, or $g(x,u)=cf(x,y(x))u^3$, etc.

Comment: How can  I find such g for a given pair $(f,y(x))$ ? Additionally, can you refer me to an appropriate book please where some examples are given?

Comment: ? In fact, as explained above, there is two cases: if $y(b)=y(a)$ (and $I\not =0$; if $I=0$, obviously $g=0$ is a solution), no solutions; if $y(b)\not =y(a)$, among the solutions are the functions $g(x,u)$ defined by $g(x,u)=f(x,y(x))h(u)$ with $\int_{y(a)}^{y(b)}h(u)du=1$. And there is certainly a lots of other solutions.

Comment: I have not seen that you have $\tilde{a}$, $\tilde{b}$. So I must add that I take these quantities equal to $a,b$. Your double integral is in fact now $\int_a^b\int_{y(a)}^{y(b)}g(x,u)dudx$ (As you have already used $y$ for your function $y(x)$, I choose $u$ for the name of the second variable of integration ). Now  with the function $g(x,u)=f(x,y(x))h(u)$ the integral $\int_{y(a)}^{y(b)}g(x,u)du=f(x,y(x))\int_{y(a)}^{y(b)}h(u)du=f(x,y(x))$, and we are done.